# Mark location from database using leaflet in laravel

Tags: laravel, leaflet

I have a table called location in my database which consists of latitude and longitude I need to mark them on the map using leaflet open street map. And I have no idea how do I do that. Till now I am only able to mark manually. If you have any resources from where I can get idea please help

This is my databa[image]se:

```
@extends('master');


@section('content');
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
      crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
      integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
      crossorigin=""></script>
<style>
    #map {position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0}
</style>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a 
   href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> 
   contributors'
   }).addTo(map);

   L.marker([19.0971904, 72.8891392]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
    .openPopup();
</script>


@endsection
```

Comment: please provide some code what you have tried so that some one can help or else difficult to predict

Comment: Yeah I updated can you help how do I do that

Comment: I was just trying I don't know how to do

Comment: I am using this for the first time and I can't find any tutorial related to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you might need to use Ajax

```
<script>

    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/leaflect",

            type: 'GET',

            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function( key, value ) {

                    L.marker([value.latitude, value.longitude]).addTo(map)
                        .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
                        .openPopup();
                })
            },
            error: function(data) {

            }
        });
    })
    </script>
```

and route will be like

```
Route::get('leaflect',[ControllerName@methodName]);
```

controller method would be like

```
public function methodName(){
    
    return Model::get();

}
```